# A content access meter

Tags: rules, users

How do Drupal publishing sites create a typical content access system (giving away some content before presenting a paywall)?

OUTCOME 1: give the anonymous user role access to X views of content type Y over a Z time period.

OUTCOME 2: give registered user role access to a bit more.

OUTCOME 3: give paid user roles even more or unlimited access.

OUTCOME 4: when the limits are reached, hide content, display a message, a modal or redirect them to [purchase a role on Ubercart](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/user/3366/selling_site_access_role_promotions).

---

Can this be achieved with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)?

I had hoped so but a promising module [Node View Count](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeviewcount) is not currently integrated into Rules.

And sadly [Limited Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/limited_views) only supports one role at a time and it is minimally maintained. Similar story for [Limit Visit](https://www.drupal.org/project/limit_visit) and [Field Paywall](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_paywall) and [Paywall](https://www.drupal.org/project/paywall) is just a placeholder.